# Scale image responsively with restrictions on both width and height

Tags: css, responsive-images

Currently I have an image with:

```
<img src="logo.png" width="100vw">
```

How do I also make the image's height 80vh if 80vh is more than 100vw?

Edit:
On narrow devices (such as phones), I want the image to occupy 100% of the viewport width
On wider devices where 100% of the viewport width exceeds 80% of the viewport height, I want the image to occupy 80% of the viewport height
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLXD1.jpg)

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. Please elaborate more

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but you can use the `max-height` and `max-width` property to set a restriction on what the value can be.

Comment: _“where 100% of the viewport width exceeds 80% of the viewport height”_ - that is a factor you can calculate, and then use in an `aspect-ratio` media query … https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with `media queries` setting the breakpoints and define the `landscape` orientation.

Example:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

    img {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 80vh;
}
```